# How to validate model object instance in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, frameworks, typeerror

I've got the following model:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    
    public static function rules() 
    {   
        return [
            'created_at'    => 'nullable',
            'updated_at'    => 'nullable',
            'name'          => 'required|string|between:1,255',
            'description'   => 'required|string|between:1,255',
            'date_added'    => 'nullable',
            'date_edited'   => 'nullable',
            'unit'          => 'required|string|between:1,255',
            'unit_type'     => 'required|integer',
            'stock'         => 'nullable|string|between:0,255',
            'barcode'       => 'nullable|string|between:0,32',
            'tax'           => 'nullable|float',
            'price'         => 'nullable|float',
            'category_id'   => 'required|integer|gt:0'
        ];
    }
}
```

And there's a controller `ProductController` that has an action `insertProduct`.

```
class class ProductController extends ApiController { // controller class

    public function insertProduct(Request $request) {
        
        $inputJson = $request->input('data_json', null);
        
        if(empty($inputJson)) {
            $inputJson = $request->getContent();
            if(empty($inputJson)) {
                return $this->errorResponse(
                    'Either data_json formdata parameter or request body should contain a JSON string.'
                );
            }
        }
        
        try {
            $product = $this->extractProductFromJSON($inputJson);
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            return $this->errorResponse($e->getMessage(), 400);
        }
        
        // When I dump the Product ($product) instance using dd(), it is just as expected and its
        // properties contain the right values.

        $validator = Validator::make($product, Product::rules());
        /* Above line causes exception:
         TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type 
         array, object given, 
         called in /.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php 
         on line 261 in file /.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Factory.php 
         on line 98
        */
        
        if($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->errorResponse($validator->errors()->first());
        }
        
        // ...
    }


    
    // How I extract the data from the JSON string (which is input).
    // Although I don't think this has anything to do with my problem.
    
    private function extractProductFromJSON(string $json) {
        
        $data = \json_decode($json);
        
        if(\json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            throw new \Exception('Error parsing JSON: ' . \json_last_error_msg());
        }
        
        try {
            
            $productData = $data->product;

            $productId = empty($productData->id) ? null : $productData->id;
            // Product id is allowed to be absent

            $product = new Product(); // My \App\Product model instance.
            $product->id = $productId;
            $product->name = $productData->name;
            $product->description = $productData->description;
            $product->date_added = $productData->date_added;
            $product->date_edited = $productData->date_edited;
            $product->unit = $productData->unit;
            $product->unit_type = $productData->unit_type;
            $product->stock = $productData->stock;
            $product->barcode = $productData->barcode;
            $product->tax = $productData->tax;
            $product->price = $productData->price;
            $product->category_id = $productData->category_id;

            return $product;
        
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            echo 'EXCEPTION...';
        }
    }

} // end of controller class
```

It seems pretty clear there's something wrong with the following line:
`$validator = Validator::make($product, Product::rules());`
The simplest cause I can think of, is that the validator simply does not accept objects and only wants arrays.
If not, what could be the problem?
If Laravel's validation only works with arrays, is it somehow possible to validate an *object*?

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    validator = Validator::make($product, Product::rules());
```

the problem is not `Product::rules()` but `$product`. `Product::rules()` is correct because it's return an array, but `$product` is an object instead of an array. You should change/convert `$product` to an array an example:

```
    validator = Validator::make((array)$product, Product::rules());
```

Comment: Isn't there anything in the framework that allows me to validate objects directly? (like if the framework internally accesses the object properties dynamically just as how it would validate an associative data array).
Otherwise, your answer seems to be the only solution.

Comment: @user2190492 you can not validate objects directly, unless you create your own validation library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You're right. If we look at the make method, we can see that it accepts rules as an array.

```
     * @param array $data
     * @param array $rules
     * @param array $messages
     * @param array $customAttributes
     * @return \Illuminate\Validation\Validator 
     * @static 
     */ 
    public static function make($data, $rules, $messages = [], $customAttributes = [])
    {
                    /** @var \Illuminate\Validation\Factory $instance */
                    return $instance->make($data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);
    }
```

I usually validate data directly in the controller

```
    $validator = Validator::make($info, [
        'shortDescription' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'countryId' => 'required',
        'cities' => 'required | array | min:1',
    ]);
```

Comment: You say it accepts the *rules* as an array (and I knew that), but my question is about the actual data to be validated. Not the rules but the data. That data is an object in my case, and I wonder if its possible to somehow validate an object instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Cliente extends Eloquent
{
    public static $autoValidates = true;
    protected static $rules = [];
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        // or static::creating, or static::updating
        static::saving(function($model)
        {
            if ($model::$autoValidates) {
                return $model->validate();
            }
        });
    }
    public function validate()
    {
    }
}
```